# 限界まで修正したのですがなぜ格納できないのかわかりません。

Tags: php, pdo

テーブルネーム　rss_feed
カラム　title,link,date
エラーメッセージなし
var_dampで確認しても値は取得できており、$stmtを確認しても格納されているようです。

無数に下記のものがサイトに表示されており意味が分からず混乱しております。
データベースを見ても同様のものが格納されております。
site
2022
0

```
<?php
try {
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=hlxclitx_wp1;host=localhost';
$user = 'hlxclitx_wp1';
$password = 'E.HrypHWxNmltXgC5eS26';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//エラーが発生した時に、例外を投げる
echo "データベースへの接続が出来ました";

}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();// err時はメッセージを表示
exit;
}

//RSSをまとめる
$url1 = [
'http://blog.livedoor.jp/dqnplus/index.rdf',
'http://alfalfalfa.com/index.rdf',
'http://himasoku.com/index.rdf',];

// insertの準備
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('insert into rss_feed (title, link, date) values (?, ?, ?)');
    
// URLのループ開始　テーブルに格納
foreach ($url1 as $url) {
    if (($rss = @simplexml_load_file($url)) === false) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($rss->item as $item) {
        $title = $item->title;
        $link = $item->link;
        $dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dc->date));
        $stmt->execute(array($title, $link, $date));
    }
    
// サイトごとに表示するなら、サイトタイトル表示はこの位置
printf('<h2>%s</h2>', $site_title);
// 個別記事のループ開始　RSSの取得が始まる
foreach ($rss->item as $item) {
if ($count >= 8) {
break;
}
++$count;
$title = $item->title;//タイトル取得
$link = $item->link;//リンクを取得
$dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');//RSSの情報を取得
$thumb = $item->thumb->url;//画像を取得
}
// 取得した記事データの表示
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM rss_feed ORDER BY date DESC';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    print('<ul>');
    printf('<li class="sitelink"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $item->link, $item->title);
    printf('<li class="sitelink"><a href="%s">site</a></li>', $item->link);
    printf('<li class="sitedate">%s</li>', $item->date);
    print('</ul>');
}
}
?>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: データベースに格納されていることが確認できるなら、ポイントはINSERTを実行しているでしょうね。ただしい値をexecuteに渡しているのか、$title等の変数をvar_dumpでデバッグしてみると何が表示されますか？

Comment: 解決することができました。格納した値が文字列として変換されていなかったようです。お手数かけまして申し訳ありません。$title = (string) $item->title; # 文字列扱いに変換

Comment: 解決したようであれば、コメント欄で終わらせずにぜひ **個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。